# how to connect to pervasive sql through odbc?

Tags: windows, database, sql-server, sql, odbc

I am trying to add a linked server to a sql server 2012 database using ssms 2012.

the linked server is pervasive sql. here's how i am trying to do it:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   @server = 'kslap208', 
   @provider = 'MSDASQL', 
   @datasrc = 'C003',
   @srvproduct = 'Pervasive'
GO
```

however when i test the connection i am getting this error msg:

[image]

what am i doing wrong? how can i link to an instance of a pervasive sql database?

here is some additional information regarding the DSN to which I am trying to connect:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check one of provided solutions explained [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive/) or the following configuration:

Linked Server: ksalap208
Provider Name: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
Product Name: Pervasive
Data Source: C003
Provider String: blank
Location: YOUR_SQLSERVER_NAM
Catalog: blank

Comment: could u summarize it as answer over here redirecting to link is good,but summarized answer would be great